# Source Code Documentation tool

Tags: .net, vb.net, documentation-generation

Can any one suggest a source code documentation tool for VB.NET 10 ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

[GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx) is what I use.  Great tool.

Comment: Thank you, but i need an open source tool for commercial use.

Comment: @Mselmi: Sorry, you didn't state that in your question.

Answer (score 4):

If you want your documentation to contain anything except the things that are already obvious from the signature, the only useful tool here is... ***you***. That and some `///` (C#) or `'''` (VB) fun.
There *are* tools that will generate things like "gets or sets the FrobCount", but ultimately... what did you *think* the `FrobCount {get;set;}` property did?

BTW, by this I *don't* mean "don't bother adding those comments" - they do have *some* sense... but my concern is that you get into the habit of ***just*** using the automatic tooling. Ultimately, this adds very little extra value. The value comes from knowledge about the semantics, expected usage, side-effects etc. No automated tool will generate that.

Answer (score 4):

We use [DocumentX](http://www.innovasys.com/products/dx2011/overview.aspx).